# Remove duplicates from user input

Tags: python

I want to ignore any duplicate entry given by user as input. I have below code :

```
def pITEMName():
    global ITEMList,fITEMList
    pITEMList = []
    fITEMList = []
    ITEMList = str(raw_input('Enter pipe separated list of ITEMS : ')).upper().strip()
    items = ITEMList.split("|")
    count = len(items)
    print  'Total Distint ITEM Count : ',  count
    pipelst = [i.replace('-mc','').replace('-MC','').replace('$','').replace('^','') for i in ITEMList.split('|')]
    filepath = '/location/data.txt'
    f = open(filepath, 'r')
    for lns in f:
            split_pipe = lns.split(':', 1)
            if split_pipe[0] in pipelst:
                    index = pipelst.index(split_pipe[0])
                    pITEMList=split_pipe[0]+"|"
                    fITEMList.append(pITEMList)
                    del pipelst[index]
    for lns in pipelst:
        print bcolors.red + lns,' is wrong ITEM Name' + bcolors.ENDC
    f.close()
```

When I execute above code it prompts me for user input as :

> Enter pipe separated list of items :

And if I provide the input as :

> Enter pipe separated list of items : AAA|IFA|AAA

After pressing enter I am getting the result as :

> Enter pipe separated list of Items : AAA|IFA|AAA
>
> Total Distint Item Count :  3
>
> AAA  is wrong Item Name
>
> Items Belonging to other Centers :
>
> Other Centers :
>
> Item Count From Other Center =  0
>
> Items Belonging to Current Centers :
>
> Active Items in  US1:
>
> ^IFA$
>
> Active Items in  US2 :
>
> ^AAA$|^AAA$
>
> Ignored Item Count From Current Center =  0
>
> You Have Entered ItemList belonging to this Center as:
> ^IFA$|^AAA$|^AAA$
>
> Active Item Count :  3
>
> Do You Want To Continue [YES|Y|NO|N] :

In above result you must be noticing that I have mentioned AAA entry twice so its counting as wrong Item. I want as duplicate entry to be ignored. Here I want to ignore the case sensitive condition also. Means If I give AAA|aaa|ifa, one 'aaa' should get ignored.

Please help me that how I can implement this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lots of great answers here; throwing my hat into the ring as well.  One straightforward way to do this:

```
items = list(set(ITEMList.split("|")))
items.sort()
```

This preserves your `items` object as a list and orders it (which is something you may or may not prefer in this case).

If you decide later that you want to return an element of your `items` list in your code, you will be able to do it by referring to the list index (this functionality doesn't exist with sets).

If you want to preserve the value of the variable `count`, you could implement the code as:

```
items = ITEMList.split("|")
count = len(items)
items = list(set(ITEMList.split("|")))
items.sort()
```

You will also want to adjust this line:

```
pipelst = [i.replace('-mc','').replace('MC','').replace('$','').replace('^','') for i in ITEMList.split('|')]
```

to this:

```
pipelst = [i.replace('-mc','').replace('MC','').replace('$','').replace('^','') for i in items]
```

Comment: Hi Daniel, by this also input is getting ignored in count only. If I am giving aaa|aaa|lll . still its showing as AAA is wrong item name, I want this not to be shown. Means I want AAA should gets treat as IFA input. because aaa is duplicate input.

Comment: Hello, @Ritesh - just added more to my answer that might help you.  Feel free to let me know if you have any other roadblocks.

Comment: I did as the same way. but duplicate entry is not getting ignored. its coming twice every where. Please have a look at the result :

Comment: I did as the same way. but duplicate entry is not getting ignored. its coming twice every where. Please have a look at the result 

Enter pipe separated list of ItemS : aaa|aaa

Total Distint Item Count :  2**

AAA  is wrong Item Name

Items Belonging to other Data Centers :

Other centers

Item Count From Other centers =  0

Items Belonging to Current Data Centers :

Stage/Test Customer Active Items in  US1:

^AAA$|^AAA$

Ignored Item Count From Current centers =  0

You Have Entered ItemList belonging to this centers as: ^AAA$|^AAA$

Active Item Count :  2

Comment: Hello, @Ritesh - just added more to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

First, you're doing `ITEMList.split("|")` several times. You should just use your already calculated `items`.

Second, you probably want:

```
items = set(ITEMList.lower().split("|"))
```

This way you get a set with unique, all lowercase elements.
I assume this doesn't matter since you can discard either uppercase or lowercase.

Answer (score 1):

If item order is not important, then a `set` will do this very well.

```
items = set(ITEMList.split("|"))
```

Comment: This doesn't take care of the case of `AAA|aaa`.

Comment: Hi Vaibhav, It just ignore the input count. rest result I am getting as same way.

Comment: Hi Santiago, `ITEMList` has been converted to uppercase in the previous line.

Answer (score 0):

if order is important

```
my_list =  "^IFA$|^AAA$|^AAA$"
"|".join(collections.Counter(my_list.upper().split("|")).keys())
```

is one way to do it

Comment: Joran, Counter class is added in python 2.7 but I have python 2.4. So getting AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Counter' error. Please let me if there is some other way around. Order is not important for me. And if I use items = set(ITEMList.split("|")) , it just ignores the duplicates in count of input. Rest result I am getting as it is.